# Setting a custom directory for Confuse YAML Configuration Files

Tags: python, yaml

I'm trying to use [this](https://confit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) library for setting up a YAML config file for a python project, but I don't want to use the suggested directories for configuration e.g. `~/.config/app` or `/etc/app` for linux. I've tried setting the path using an environment variable as outlined in the documentation here.

Does anybody have any experience of getting this to work using the environment variables?

I can't really understand why the API doesn't just let you pass a file path, this approach seems unnecessarily complex to me. I suspect there is a good reason I just don't understand! I would have thought in most cases the config file will be in your python project directory?

Comment: Seems `confuse` is not a good tool for you. Why don't you use just plain `yaml` and add handlers for reading/storing the config in your custom path?

Comment: @Mikaelblomkvistsson This is what I have done now, but I was also interested to understand how I was mis-using confuse. It's designed for exactly this situation it seems

Comment: I don't understand — is the solution using the environment variable not working for you?

Comment: @L3viathan That's correct, I can't get this to work with the environment variable

Comment: I too can't get the environment variable method to work. And I don't think needing a custom directory makes confuse the wrong tool for the job: it introduces a number of conveniences and that's why I (and probably OP) want to use it and not parse YAML manually or with more unwieldy modules.

Comment: @soundofsilence could you add some details on what you've tried regarding the environmental variable approach? I was actually able to make it work at least for my desired value of "." for the current working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm experimenting with the library and so far in order to put a config.yaml file in the root folder of my script I just did that:

```py
import confuse


class MyConfiguration(confuse.Configuration):
    def config_dir(self):
        return './'


config = MyConfiguration('SplitwiseToBuckets')

print(config)
```

Quite rude I know but for what I want so far it works..! :D